# Spring Integration config errror: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

Can you help with spring integration config.

After receiving message I got:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'myapp-1.scMyRequestChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=input me, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@6c7a1290, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, jms_destination=queue:///SYN.REQ, JMSXUserID=mqm         , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1590129774770, JMSXAppID=hermes.browser.HermesBrowser, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@6c7a1290, jms_redelivered=true, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20200522, JMSXDeliveryCount=649, JMS_IBM_PutTime=06425480, id=ed13c600-56b5-33ff-7228-0a5d146b618b, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d31202020202020202020aa6fc75e004d3e12, timestamp=1590135772781}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:499) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:470) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.sendAndReceiveMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:511) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:344) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179) [spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076) [spring-jms-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

My code:

```
@Configuration
public class MyEndpointConfiguration {
    public static final String SC_My_REQUEST_CHANNEL = "scMyRequestChannel";
    public static final String SC_My_RESPONSE_CHANNEL = "scMyResponseChannel";

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel scMyRequestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel scMyResponseChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter myMessageConverter() {
        return new MyMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    JmsInboundGateway myJmsInboundGateway(ConnectionFactory myConnectionFactory,
                                           MessageConverter myMessageConverter,
                                           MessageChannel scMyRequestChannel,
                                           MessageChannel scMyResponseChannel,
                                           Destination myScRequestDestination,
                                           Destination myScResponseDestination) {
        return Jms
                .inboundGateway(myConnectionFactory)
                .destination(myScRequestDestination)
                .defaultReplyDestination(myScResponseDestination)
                .requestChannel(scMyRequestChannel)
                .replyChannel(scMyResponseChannel)
                .jmsMessageConverter(myMessageConverter)
                .get();
    }

    public IntegrationFlow getFromConvertAndPutToSpring(JmsInboundGateway myJmsInboundGateway) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(myJmsInboundGateway)
                .handle((p,h) -> "my answer")
                .logAndReply("inbound");
    }

//    public IntegrationFlow getFromInputChannel(MessageChannel scMyRequestChannel) {
//        return IntegrationFlows
//                .from(scMyRequestChannel)
//                .log("sc input")
//                .handle((p,h) -> "my answer")
//                .log()
//                .nullChannel();
//    }
}
```

I have simillar JmsInboudGateway config for other queue without .requestChannel and .replyChannel and it well.

If instead of injecting request channel bean I declare it with text name got this

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: No request channel available. Cannot send request message.
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:479) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:470) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.sendAndReceiveMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:511) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
```

And more text for publicating question in sof.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it looks like I miss Bean annotation in process of testing.

Comment: Good. Please, add all the info required for the fix. You might be not only one with similar problem. Then you can accept your own answer.